# Installing Samsung printer driver for SL-M2020W/XAA in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, printing, samsung

I just purchased a new Samsung Xpress SL-M2020W/XAA printer and am having trouble installing the drivers.  The printer application does recognize the printer but when it searches for the drivers, they are not found.  I have downloaded the Linux drivers from the Samsung web site and which are in my downloads folder but I cant seem to get to that directory from a command line.  Can anyone help me?  Thanks!

Comment: How are you unable to get to your downloads directory?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a Terminal pointing error.  The hierarchy works similar to most file system out there.  However, commands are a bit different.  First off ensure you are indeed downloading to the Download folder.  A simple Ctrl + Alt + T will bring up a terminal; this you should see

```
User(@yourmachinename):~$
```

Here you wil type exactly

```
cd Downloads
```

then

```
dir
```

`ls` works here to, but, keeping this simple you should find the package you are looking for.  Also make certain the driver are Linux compatible with the Printer you have and CUPS is running.  Make certain to open the README or INSTALL file first before anything else.

Comment: Do not forget to check it as an answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

just install generic-pcl-laser driver from the list of printer models thats worked for me

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: This generic driver did not work for me on ubuntu 16.04